# ExoPlayer - Android Studio IDE

Tags: android-studio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Hello i'm trying to use ExoPlayer in my app for showing a stream by url but when i add "implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.19.1'" android studio gives me a error: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

I did anything to fix it and no videos about it in web

Answer (score 0):

Fix it.
replace "implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.19.1'" whit "implementation(libs.exoplayer)"